# Is it possible to deploy a raw Java web app to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

*Very inexperienced user here...please be patient!*

I inherited maintenance of Heroku app from someone no longer with the company.  Having to re-deploy an app update is probably a once-a-year event, and here we are.

The instructions I have include building a standalone jar file containing my app and then deploying it to Heroku.  Specifically the procedure for this is to use the Heroku CLI with the following command:

```
heroku deploy:jar webapp.jar -a my-app
```

Easy enough.  Except he had his own instance of the Heroku CLI, and when I went to download my own copy, it appears that the `deploy` command no longer exists! Is this the case?  Is this a deprecated command?  Do I need to go through the process of figuring out how to set up a git repository to deploy this?  (We are in fact using git to manage the source for this app, but it's behind our company firewall, so I'm not sure how practical/difficult it will be to set this up for Heroku).  I just want to make sure I'm not missing something simple before investing a significant amount of time re-inventing the deployment process.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular mechanism is indeed to push the code from git to Heroku, providing the necessary files (i.e. profcile) to deploy the runtime.
An alternative is to create a Docker image and push it to the Heroku Registry (which in your case would require more reworking).

Refer to [Deploy with Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git), the firewall should not be a problem as Heroku will not access your code, but you will need to perform the push (`git push heroku master`)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  This has certainly opened up a can of worms, however, and is not as simple as it sounds.

For one thing (and for whatever reason) the source repository is actually a collection of different sub-repositories that the original author extracted into a scratch area used to build the final uberjar (possibly a holdover from a previous system he used).  Also, he installed his only local copy of the maven libraries he was using.  So I am still pushing through trying to come up with a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have to answer my own question because I was able to find the solution.

It turns out there is a plugin available for the heroku CLI that provides the deploy command.  Running `heroku plugins:install java` will install the plugin that provides the deploy command in the heroku CLI.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files for more information.